# PHP Mysql Increment by 1 with group by some field

Tags: php, mysql

Look th etable below

```
 +----+---------+---------+----+---------+---------+
| id |  name   | order   | one|  two    | three   |
+----+---------+---------+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | stan    |    1    |  5 |  suger  |   true  |
|  2 | kyle    |    1    |  4 |  coffe  |    yes  |
|  3 | stan    |    2    |  3 |  banana |    no   |
|  4 | kyle    |    2    |  4 |  orange |    false|
+----+---------+---------+----+---------+---------+
```

As you see from above I have two stan and two kyle. Now what happen is if I add a nother stan, I need the Code to see how many is the max number in order and add the row with adding +1 to the order field.

In short, add a row to mysql table increment the order by one +1 group by name. How do I achieve that in PHP and Mysql? or I think can be handled in Mysql Query only?

So, If I need to add the following information,

5 stan (calculate order) 3 banana true.

Comment: It would not be possible to do it in a single query due to possible data race.

Comment: it is... the single query would contain another query in it though

Comment: even if i have to use more than one query, how do I achieve that?

Comment: @Ice76 please provide one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though its a bad idea to group by name since multiple people can have the same name, here's what I think the solution would look like:

```
select name, max(`order`)+1 
from orders 
group by name;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b25dbf/3/0

For adding the value to the table:

```
insert into orders(name,`order`) 
select name, max(`order`)+1 
from orders 
where name='stan'
group by name;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01db84/1

Adding multiple values:

```
insert into orders(name,`order`,one,two,three) 
select name, max(`order`)+1 , 3, 'banana', true
from orders 
where name='stan'
group by name;
```

Comment: you solution seems near, but I need to insert not select! how?

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments above, this query is a subject to data race.

Comment: Added SQL for inserting into the table. And I agree, the way the data is represented is not ideal. I would not use this for anything with very high rates of transactions unless its just for creating backup logs

Comment: you really are so near, only one issue. if i have more that two column how do i add the rest fields. i can't see value list in your insert query

Comment: Since you are grouping by name, you have to decide how you want to aggregate the rest of the columns. For each name you might have multiple values for each column so you have to decide which aggregate function you want to apply for each one e.g. min, max, avg, etc. In the example `order` was just one of the columns and I used max()+1 as the aggregate function

Comment: let me update the table again you could see it easly

Comment: 5 - stan - (calculate order) - 3 - banana - true.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the updated question